# registerusernotificationsettings not work after using unregisterForRemoteNotifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to use in my app something like disabler and enabler of push notifications. I use code like this. Also I activate notifications in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` with code from `sender.isOn`

```m
if (sender.isOn) {

    self.notificationLabel.text = @"Notifications enabled";

    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

} else {

    self.notificationLabel.text = @"Notifications disabled";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];

}
```

But after first use `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` my app not initialling notifications with `registerForRemoteNotifications`. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution: Uninstall the app and delete that code!**

It took me many hours and 3 broken test devices to track this one down..!

This line is **bad**:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications] //DON'T DO IT!
```

It puts the app in an unstable state where calling `registerForRemoteNotifications` no longer works.

This line is equally **nasty**:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications] //CALL ME ONCE!
```

You must call it once, and only once, per run of your app. If you happen to call it twice, notifications will mysteriously break.