# Firebase FCM Instance ID is nil (running quickstart app on real device)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging

Running the FCM demo app on my iPhone doesn't work - The Firebase ID is **nil**.

Steps to reproduce:

1. `pod try Firebase`, and run `10: quickstart-ios/messaging/FCM.xcodeproj`
2. Copy my `GoogleService-Info.plist` file into the project
3. Run the app on an iPhone 5s (iOS 9.3.2)
4. Accept the dialog requesting permission to send notifications
5. Click the buttons
6. The Instance Id token is **nil**

My Mac has the appropriate certificates to develop and deploy apps:

1. I have both iOS distribution and iOS development provisioning
   profiles, chosen using the 'automatic' settings.
2. I have both iOS distribution and iOS development certificates installed, code-signed using the 'automatic: iPhone developer' option
3. I have the 'Production' SSL certificate installed: "Apple Push Notification
   service SSL (Sandbox & Production)"

I see lots of noise in the logs, but the most significant error is this one:

```
Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=0 "(null)"
```

Here is the full console output:

```
2016-06-25 16:15:08.339 FCM[7398:4128979] Configuring the default app.
2016-06-25 16:15:08.383 FCM[7398:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
2016-06-25 16:15:08.396: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-06-25 16:15:08.397: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
2016-06-25 16:15:08.403: <FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.1.0
2016-06-25 16:15:08.413: <FIRMessaging/WARNING> FIRMessaging AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification receiver handlers. Add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-06-25 16:15:08.443 FCM[7398:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2016-06-25 16:15:08.508 FCM[7398:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
2016-06-25 16:15:08.538: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> APNS Environment in profile: development
2016-06-25 16:15:08.848 FCM[7398:4128979] Connected to FCM.
2016-06-25 16:15:08.893: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=0 "(null)"
2016-06-25 16:15:22.311: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=0 "(null)"
2016-06-25 16:15:36.774 FCM[7398:4128979] Unable to connect to FCM. Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=2001 "(null)"
2016-06-25 16:15:40.552 FCM[7398:4128979] Subscribed to news topic
2016-06-25 16:15:43.100 FCM[7398:4128979] InstanceID token: (null)
2016-06-25 16:15:49.036: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=0 "(null)"
2016-06-25 16:16:31.022: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=0 "(null)"
2016-06-25 16:17:32.976: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=0 "(null)"
2016-06-25 16:17:32.976: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to retrieve the default GCM token after 5 retries
2016-06-25 16:19:10.662 FCM[7398:4128979] InstanceID token: (null)
2016-06-25 16:19:10.980: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=0 "(null)"
2016-06-25 16:19:10.981: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to retrieve the default GCM token after 5 retries
```

Comment: Seeing the same on an iPad 2 (9.3).

Comment: Note that the issue is only when I deploy to a real device. It works fine in the simulator, meaning that my provisioning profile and certificates are correct, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as installing the APNs SSL certificates on your dev machine, you also need to upload them to the Firebase Console!

[https://console.firebase.google.com/project/*your-project-name-here*/settings/cloudmessaging](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_your-project-name-here_/settings/cloudmessaging)

Comment: Curiously, it will work for a while without doing this, but then it will unexpectedly stop working and make your teeth to go grey.

Answer (score 3):

Try updating Firebase/Core to v3.4.4, it fixed unexpected errors for me. Otherwise the typical fixes are:

- Enabling `Push Notifications` under the app's `Capabilities`
- Avoid calling `unregisterForRemoteNotifications`. After this call, you can't register the device anymore to push notifications.
- Setting `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to `NO` in your info.plist file. I think there are bugs with their method swizzling.
- Calling `[[FIRMessaging messaging] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeUnknown]` in the method `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran the same code on the simulator (iPhone 5, iOS 9.3), and I get a token without any trouble.

I do see lots of the same warnings, though...

```
2016-06-25 16:38:31.353 FCM[2546:42455] Configuring the default app.
2016-06-25 16:38:32.561 FCM[2546:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
2016-06-25 16:38:32.833 FCM[2546:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2016-06-25 16:38:32.901: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-06-25 16:38:32.928: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
2016-06-25 16:38:32.971: <FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.1.0
2016-06-25 16:38:33.189: <FIRMessaging/WARNING> FIRMessaging AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification receiver handlers. Add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-06-25 16:38:51.094: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_SIMULATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED_NSERROR_DESCRIPTION" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_SIMULATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED_NSERROR_DESCRIPTION}
2016-06-25 16:38:51.096: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_SIMULATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED_NSERROR_DESCRIPTION" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=REMOTE_NOTIFICATION_SIMULATOR_NOT_SUPPORTED_NSERROR_DESCRIPTION}
2016-06-25 16:38:51.140 FCM[2546:42883] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2016-06-25 16:38:51.141 FCM[2546:42883] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2016-06-25 16:38:51.460 FCM[2546:42455] Connected to FCM.
2016-06-25 16:38:56.709 FCM[2546:42455] InstanceID token: fgbPv5tnsPk:APA91bHUWOmuLmd4UkLXcp3Lysp92fH6bOb7tfmbjHehFOt_NPnc6tnMk-7YT51VASkk-dyHZAl01QRcedwqGUhHMiIXeV_xknBXppncu0WyjKLYhaVQ08bYKNZ5M1CuSjtk9l0HPyJX
2016-06-25 16:38:56.711 FCM[2546:42455] Unable to connect to FCM. Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=2001 "(null)"
2016-06-25 16:38:57.505 FCM[2546:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
2016-06-25 16:40:03.845 FCM[2546:42455] Unable to connect to FCM. Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=2001 "(null)"
2016-06-25 16:40:06.534 FCM[2546:42455] InstanceID token: fgbPv5tns9......
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to my use of the 'Production' SSL certificate, instead of the 'Development' one. Installing that seemed to fix things.

I had wrongly assumed that both development and production versions would be handled by the "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)" certificate. That may be the case for native APNs, but it doesn't work for Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ever happened to run this command:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications],
```

your app will not be able to register for remote notifications.

[registerusernotificationsettings not work after using unregisterForRemoteNotifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950399/registerusernotificationsettings-not-work-after-using-unregisterforremotenotific/)

You need to uninstall the app to get it working again...

Answer (score 0):

For me, If happened when i do not use FIRAuth before get values from Firebase.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: "test1@gmail.com", password: "123456", completion: { (user, error) in
if(error != nil){
    print(error)
    return
}


let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://firdemo-84b6b.firebaseio.com/").child("users")

ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.key)
    print(snapshot.value)
    }, withCancel: { (error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print(error)
            return
        }
    })

})
```

Please try it. And let me know if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Add Your APNS.p12 in Firebase in Cloud Messaging Tab

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/VBTechlabsApp(YOUR_APP_NAME)/settings/cloudmessaging